# Sphinx HTML builder renders unnecessary script tags

Tags: python, python-sphinx

The `Sphinx` HTML builder renders script tags which are in my case unnecessary.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_static/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_static/underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_static/doctools.js"></script>
```

They add considerable lag to the page load. Is there a way to prevent the builder from rendering these tags?

This is how it is done in the layout.html template from the basic theme:

```
{%- for scriptfile in script_files %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ pathto(scriptfile, 1) }}"></script>
{%- endfor %}
```

It is hard coded in the `StandaloneHTMLBuilder(Builder)` class:

```
# This is a class attribute because it is mutated by Sphinx.add_javascript.
script_files = ['_static/jquery.js', '_static/underscore.js',
                '_static/doctools.js']
```